# How to get an object in singleton?

Tags: java, singleton

I create a public function method() is defined inside the class Singleton (HouseCreator) for add new object. But I don't know how to call or get an object inside this.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my source code :

It is my main class >

```
public class TestSingleton {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
             HouseCreator hc = HouseCreator.getInstance();
              House h1 = hc.createHouse("A5B6","red");
              House h2 = hc.createHouse("GP44","blue");               
    }
}
```

and

```
class HouseCreator{
    private static HouseCreator instance = new HouseCreator();
    private HouseCreator(){
    }
    public static HouseCreator getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
    public House createHouse(String address,String color){
       boolean alreadyCreate = true;
        if(alreadyCreate){
            return null;
        }else{
        return new House(address, color);
        }
    }
}

class House{
    private String address;
    private String  color;

    public House() {
    }

    public House(String address, String color) {
        this.address = address;
        this.color = color;
   }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: `boolean alreadyCreate = true;  if(alreadyCreate){ return null;`.... This is always true and will always return `null`.

Comment: You use Singleton for HouseCreator and this singleton should build only one House instance ?^^

Comment: The recommended approach in Java 5+ is to use an enum with a single value `INSTANCE`.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose if to never create the *same* `House` twice, so never instanciate 2 Houses that are equals looking to their adress and color, you can store them in a `List`

If the house you're looking for is already in the list you'll get it (and the new instanciate one will be garbaged), if not keep the one you instanciate and add it to the list

```
class HouseCreator{
    private static HouseCreator instance = new HouseCreator();
    private List<House> houses;

    private HouseCreator(){
        houses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static HouseCreator getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public House createHouse(String address,String color){
        House h = new House(address, color);
        int indexOf = houses.indexOf(h);
        if(indexOf < 0){
            houses.add(h);
            return h;
        }else{
            return houses.get(indexOf);
        }
    }
}
```

And in `House` class add the `equals` method

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    House house = (House) o;
    return Objects.equals(address, house.address) && Objects.equals(color, house.color);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to store the houses you create somewhere.

They are created based on the address and color - this is the key, and it is how you need to keep track of them:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class HouseCreator {
    private static HouseCreator instance = new HouseCreator();

    private final Map<HouseKey, House> createdHouses = new HashMap<>();

    private HouseCreator() {
    }

    public static HouseCreator getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public House createHouse(String address, String color) {
        return createdHouses.computeIfAbsent(new HouseKey(address, color), x -> new House(address, color));
    }
}

class HouseKey {
    private String address;
    private String color;

    public HouseKey(String address, String color) {
        this.address = address;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((color == null) ? 0 : color.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        HouseKey other = (HouseKey) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
            return false;
        if (color == null) {
            if (other.color != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!color.equals(other.color))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

class House {
    private String address;
    private String color;

    public House() {
    }

    public House(String address, String color) {
        this.address = address;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create an HouseKey as it's holds exactly the same as House, so you have 2 times more data than required

Comment: ...or make House hold the HouseKey. You need something to encapsulate the { address, color } tuple